# Scaled vs. unscaled Chi-square statistic in CFA / GRM fit evaluation

Tags: chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, structural-equation-modeling, psychometrics

I generally want to assess the fit of a CFA model with ordered categorical indicators (the graded response model, GRM). There are two versions of this model, the normal-ogive GRM (ordered CFA with probit link function) and the logistic GRM; the choice is not of central concern to me.

As far as I can see there are two ways of estimating the models, marginal maximum likelihood and weighted least squares. Both procedures lead to a model chi-square for testing goodness of fit. Satorra suggested the scaled Chi-square statistic as a more robust statistic when the data are not normal. Apparently it is also more accurate in small samples.

When I estimate the GRM models, MPlus automatically returns the scaled Chi-square with its p-value; Lavaan returns both the scaled and unscaled versions of Chi-square (when estimating the normal GRM; Lavaan currently cannot estimate the logistic, as far as I know). In addition we get CFI, RMSEA, and TLI, which in Mplus are based on the scaled Chi-square and in Lavaan we again get unscaled and scaled versions, respectively, which we be inclined to “choose” from.

My questions are:

- What is the reason we may want to use the scaled Chi-square (as a default as they do it in Mplus)? Intuitively, we could also use the unscaled version if we know the distribution of the latent indicators is normal – is this true? Lavaan at least gives the user a choice which may hint to the fact that it is actually a free decision, based on the user’s assumptions.
- I don’t find references on whether to use CFI, RMSEA, TLI with scaled or non-scaled Chi-square. Is there a strong advice on which one to use? Again Mplus default are the scaled versions. While scaled chi-square may reassure against non-normality in statistical tests, however, it seems that its behavior in the three fit statistics is not fully clear. Has it been shown that scaled CFI/RMSEA/TLI are more robust in case of non normality?

Comment: Are you using estimator = ML, and estimator = WLSMV? Or something else.

Comment: In MPlus I would use estimator = ML to get the logistic GRM and WLSMV to get the normal GRM. Those are the defaults as far as I understand. Lavaan would only estimate the logistic GRM, but then WLS, either DWLS or WLSMV.